# Trouble booting from usb (Compaq dc7600 Small Form Factor)

Tags: windows-xp, bios, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.04, usb-boot

I have been trying over the last few days to boot from a bootable usb pen drive on my [Compaq dc7600 Small Form Factor desktop](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF06b/12132708-12132884-12132884-12132884-12221730-12221860-77923637.html?dnr=1) PC so I can dual-boot, but to no avail. The pen drive contains Ubuntu 12.04.3 and I have double checked it on another PC (of a different model) and it **IS** bootable. I have changed the BIOS boot order and selected the option to boot from usb, but it will not boot from usb.

My current BIOS version is Hewlett-Packard 786d1 v01.03 (outdated, possibly the problem?) and I am running Windows XP Professional SP3.

So what I need to know is:

- Do I need to change some other sort of BIOS setting?
- Do I need to update the BIOS?
- Boot from some other media?
- Something else?

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**Update:** I have just updated the BIOS to version 1.61. Does this help my situation?

Comment: Did you checked your USB port?

Comment: I have tried all of the usb ports on the machine

Comment: I have not yet tried to boot from a disk, but I want to actually see if I CAN boot from usb. A disk will just be a fallback option if that fails

Answer (score 1):

Bit late for an answer (2 years) but anyway... you have to change the boot order in BIOS by pressing F10 at startup (not just via F9, despite what the menu suggests).

Comment: The system in question has since changed hands, but I do recall changing the boot order - still didn't work. Thanks anyway :)